# CDN for blueprint css framework

Tags: cdn, blueprint-css

Does anyone know a free CDN for blueprint css framework

Comment: you can try to use [jare.io](http://www.jare.io), a free and instant CDN

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it's not technically a CDN but you can link directly to github

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/raw/master/blueprint/print.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/raw/master/blueprint/screen.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/raw/master/blueprint/ie.css"/>
```

I haven't tried this myself, and don't know if they might change it at any given moment.  But it's a solution for not having to host it yourself.

For me, I would put it on my own server, I prefer not to have the dependency, and they are small files.  But if you're trying to squeeze every ms I'd test it.  Your servers may be faster, and a connection to them is already established.

At the same time, many browsers have a connection limit for each domain, so you may get parallel downloads, also a CDN is nice because the user often has the resource already cached (although, not likely in this case).

Personally, I wouldn't do it, unless it's Google, Microsoft, Amazon, etc...  and they're putting it on their servers specifically for the purpose.  I use the Google CDN for jQuery, and it's great.  But Blueprint just isn't there yet.

Comment: Hi Dan,

thanks for the replay. One little question.. what do you think about the loading performance

I will try this by myself and post the results

thanks again

sameera

Comment: -1, you want a CDN to have good performance and caching behavior, which GitHub's raw view of a file doesn't

Comment: yup, my first sentence "Well, it's not technically a CDN". It may not be the answer he wanted, doesn't mean it's a bad answer.

Comment: Thanks figuring and alternate... +1 from me. it is helpful when doing basic development work.