# public URLs for common resources

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization

I have been told that a great way to decrease the load on my own site is pointing known CSS and JS to public URLs.

For instance, JQuery or Blueprint. 
This allows caching as it is very possible that the user has visited previously other page pointing to the same scripts/stylesheets.

I would like to have a list of those public URLs, I think this question can become a good reference. 
I am particularly interested in Blueprint

Comment: Not an answer, but this is why I have switched back to hosting everything myself: [Why is jQuery tools CDN link pointing to an ad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471568/why-is-jquery-tools-cdn-link-pointing-to-an-ad)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CDN for blueprint css framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899870/cdn-for-blueprint-css-framework)

Comment: This is called a "Content Delivery Network", not public URL. Search for those and you will find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone asked the same question for blueprint before: [CDN for blueprint css framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899870/cdn-for-blueprint-css-framework)

Here you can find more common use lib:
http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/libraries/devguide.html